# Ubuntu Wifi over 40 times SLOWER than FreeBSD and Windows drivers

Tags: drivers, wireless, atheros

What gives with Ubuntu's AWFUL Wifi support?

```
~$ uname -a

Linux CQF-MSI 4.13.0-37-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 7 16:03:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lspci | awk '/[Nn]et/ {print $1}' | xargs -i% lspci -ks %

04:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 20)
Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Killer N1525 Wireless-AC
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

[image: freebsd wifi speed 300Mbits]

[image: Ubuntu 16.04.1 wifi speed 7Mbits]

I have already tried:

```
sudo modprobe -rfv ath10k_pci
sudo modprobe -v ath10k_pci nohwcrypt=1
```

And

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
cd linux-firmware
sudo cp -r * /lib/firmware
```

No luck at all.

WHAT GIVES?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

The Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 with the ath10k_pci driver is a lemon and not just in the Ubuntu distros. [As discussed here.](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/qca6174-slow-lan-transfers/35942/10)